# aptitude search output

Tags: aptitude, synaptic

Can someone please explain this situation to me?

I do an aptitude search and I get the following output:

```
i package  ...
p package:i386 ...
```

When I start up synaptic I see package but not package:i386

Also can someone clarify what the p and I stand for?

Answer (score 11):

The i and p mean that the package is either installed or is a package that's available to be installed.

#### For example

```
$ aptitude search aptitude
i   aptitude              - terminal-based package manager
p   aptitude:i386         - terminal-based package manager
i A aptitude-common       - architecture indepedent files for the aptitude package manager
p   aptitude-dbg          - Debug symbols for the aptitude package manager
p   aptitude-dbg:i386     - Debug symbols for the aptitude package manager
v   aptitude-doc          -
```

#### man page

From `man aptitude`:

> Unless you pass the -F option, the output of aptitude search will look
>   something like this:

**output**

```
 i   apt                             - Advanced front-end for dpkg
 pi  apt-build                       - frontend to apt to build, optimize and in 
 cp  apt-file                        - APT package searching utility -- command-
 ihA raptor-utils                    - Raptor RDF Parser utilities
```

**description**

> Each search result is listed on a separate line. The first character
>   of each line indicates the current state of the package: the most
>   common states are **p**, meaning that no trace of the package exists on
>   the system, **c**, meaning that the package was deleted but its
>   configuration files remain on the system, **i**, meaning that the package
>   is installed, and **v**, meaning that the package is virtual. The second
>   character indicates the stored action (if any; otherwise a blank space
>   is displayed) to  be performed on the package, with the most common
>   actions being **i**, meaning that the package will be installed, **d**,
>   meaning that the package will be deleted, and **p**,  meaning that the
>   package and its configuration files will be removed. If the third
>   character is **A**, the package was automatically installed.

#### References

- [Ubuntu aptitude man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/aptitude.8.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have an amd64 system with multiarch support.

Packages with no architecture indication are either for your native architecture (i.e. here amd64) or architecture-independent. Packages for another architecture have `:ARCHNAME` appended to them in the Aptitude output, e.g. `:i386` for a 32-bit package on an x86 (PC) system.

You're seeing a lot of `i package` (`package` for the native architecture is **i**nstalled) and `p package:i386` (`package` for the architecture `i386` is not installed — it is [**p**urged](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_the_event_flow_of_the_package_management)) because on a typical system, few non-native packages are installed. For the most part, non-native packages are used to provide libraries for third-party programs.

Synaptic isn't showing the non-native packages. This may be an old bug or a new configuration option — I don't know as I'm not familiar enough with Synaptic.