# How to read the first field of output returned by `apt search`?

Tags: apt

I guess `i` is installed, but the others?

```
$ apt search * | sort -t' ' -k1 | cut -c1 | uniq
c
i
p
v
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `ls`, in the same directory you ran the `apt` command above?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73805/338177

Comment: @StephenKitt how would `ls` be relevant? I think it was from the directory created by `tar emacs-26.3.tar.xz`.

Comment: So, based on @guillermochamorro answer my guess was completely wrong. Which leaves open the question: how to know search and check for installed at the same time?

Comment: @Erwann it’s relevant because `apt search *` expands `*` with the names of the files in the current directory.

Comment: It should have been `apt search .*` or `apt-cache search .*`. They return 108063 and 64639 lines respectively.

Comment: @Erwann those would have had the same problem, expanding `.*`, unless you quoted them or escaped the `*`. But unlike `aptitude search` which the linked question refers to, `apt search` and `apt-cache` search output the package name first, so the first character in the line wouldn’t give you any information about the state of the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt search`’s output takes the form

```
package name/suites version architecture [state]
  description
```

so extracting the first column won’t give much useful information.

Addressing your updated question from [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549377/how-to-read-the-first-field-of-output-returned-by-apt-search#comment1019728_549377), “how to know search and check for installed at the same time?”, you can use

```
apt search $pattern | grep -A1 '\[.*installed.*\]'
```

This will show the installed packages matching `$pattern`; for example on my system

```
$ apt search evdev | grep -A1 '\[.*installed.*\]'

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

evemu-tools/stable,now 2.7.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Linux Input Event Device Emulation Library - test tools
--
joystick/stable,now 1:1.6.1-1 amd64 [installed]
  set of testing and calibration tools for joysticks
--
libevdev-build-deps/now 1.6.0+dfsg-1 all [installed,local]
  build-dependencies for libevdev
--
```

etc.

The warning is irrelevant here; you can’t avoid it by using `apt-cache` instead because `apt-cache` doesn’t show all the information needed.

You can also [use `aptitude`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104374/86440):

```
aptitude search '~i evdev`
```

will search for installed packages matching “evdev”.

Comment: "so extracting the first column won’t give much useful information": that's a straw man since I had already acknowledged I had mistaken the first column for the state. Output of `apt search` on my platform/setup does not specify `[state]` in any column. So, this does not solve my question.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what platform you’re using?

Comment: `$ uname -a; cat /etc/*-release | grep DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION
Linux laptop 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
cat: /etc/upstream-releaseDISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 19 Tara"`

Comment: Try `aptitude` then, see my updated answer.